# How do I hide Material Bottom App Bar when Coordinator Layout's child fragment is scrolled?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, material-ui, material-components-android

I wonder why `app:hideOnScroll="true"` is not working in my case, when I want my `BottomAppBar` to be hidden when scrolling.
I want to achieve something like this: [Hide bottom app bar on scroll](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-components%2F1579302979877%2Fassets%2F1gaSrddolFHd8BwOioeYz0ODiyEhCevtn%2Fbehavior-scroll.mp4)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/customtoolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBtn"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundPrimary"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackgroundPrimary"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root element of `content_main.xml` should be `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView` if you want to enable `hideOnScroll`

Comment: I changed the roof element to nestedScrollView but now I can't scroll at all

Comment: The problem was that I completely replaced ```ConstraintLayout``` to a ```NestedScrollView```! As soon as I added a ```ConstraintLayout``` ***between*** the ```NestedScrollView``` and the ```FrameLayout```, it worked. So the hierarchy of ```content_main.xml``` is now: ```NestedScrollView``` > ```ConstraintLayout``` > ```FrameLayout```. Thanks!